# Can be inherit singleton class in typescript?

Tags: typescript, singleton

I need to inherit singleton class and override it's method. is it possible in typescript? or any other way to implement this type of scenario in typescript.

// Parent Class

```
export class SFSCommands {
    static instance: SFSCommands;
    protected constructor() {
        if (SFSCommands.instance) {
            return SFSCommands.instance;
        }

        setInterval(() => {
            this.initSfsCommands('sss');
        }, 2000);
    }

    static getInstance() {
        if (!SFSCommands.instance) {
            SFSCommands.instance = new SFSCommands();
        }
        return SFSCommands.instance;
    }

    initSfsCommands(e: any) {
        console.log('comming in service');
    }
}
```

//**** Child Class ***********

```
import { SFSCommands } from '../utility/sfscommands';

export abstract class GameModel extends SFSCommands {
    roomName: string;

    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log(this);
    }

    // called from child whien game component inisilized

    initSfsCommands(event: any) {
        console.log('game model');
    }

}
```

I call **SFSCommands.getInstance()** from my **app.component.ts** file

Comment: The tried code will be more helpful!

Comment: @Sandeep look at this link https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Comment: what do you mean by singleton class?

Comment: @Ludevik singleton class means we initialised class memory only once and after that we share same instance.

Comment: so you mean singleton service, provided in root module and you want to override just one method of that service, right?

Comment: @Ludevik you can say that, but actually I have a pure ts class and I make it singleton. after that other classes inherit it.

Comment: @Sandeep Why do you think it's not possible?

Comment: @Sandeep could you post your code? to show us how you made the class singleton and how other classes inherit it?

Comment: @zmag and Ludevik I post my code

Answer (score 1):

An Angular injectable/service class is a singleton.

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class GlobalService {}
```

It will be instantiated when you first inject it in a component.

```
constructor(private globalService: GlobalService){}
```

Comment: thanks @Carsten but I need to method overriding also.

Answer (score 0):

It is not nice but it is possible

```
export class GameModel extends SFSCommands {
  static getInstance() {
    super.getInstance().initSfsCommands = (event: any) => {
      console.log('game model');
    }
    return GameModel.instance;
  }
}
```

and you should call `GameModel.getInstance()` instead of `SFSCommands.getInstance()`

Hope this help

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: When you call getInstance() from SFSCommands, you construct the SFSCommands, not GameModel. SFSCommands will never know the existence of the GameModel. Therefore it couldn't know the initSfsCommands from GameModel.

Comment: So you need to rewrite the function instead of waiting the function from GameModel to be called. That's why we have ```super.getInstance().initSfsCommands = (event: any) => {
      console.log('game model');
    }```

Comment: However I said it is not nice, because it totally rewrite the function from the SFSCommands. That mean even later you call SFSCommands.getInstall, it will call the new function